# IncompatibleClassChangeError when testing SpringDataJpa using DbUnit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

It seems this situation appears before, and was asked& answered, but situation is changed because of updated versions...

I tried my Spring DBUnit test with default configuration (connecting to `h2db`, i've checked, h2db is used correctly):

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseTestConfig.class})
  @TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
          DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
  @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
```

`test-application.properties` is empty.
test dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

project dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

error that i've got:

```
  14:01:58.162 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener@411f53a0] to prepare test instance [com.nextiva.calendar.client.google.GoogleEventProcessorIntegrationTest@198b6731]
  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:78)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've tried downgrade spring-boot version to `1.4.0` - same error.
I hope someone can help me with the issue or suggest how to determine version compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I used too old version of `spring-test-dbunit` (I've used old article). I've replaced it with:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and it works now.